# Apply function accross multiple columns within group_by in Polars

Tags: python-polars

Given this dataframe:

```
polars_df = pl.DataFrame({
    "name": ["A","B","C"],
    "group": ["a","a","b"],
    "val1": [1, None, 3],
    "val2": [1, 5, None],
    "val3": [None, None, 3],
})
```

I want to calculate the mean and count the number of NAs within the three val* columns for each group. So the result should look like:

```
pl.DataFrame([
    {'group': 'a', 'mean': 2.0, 'percentage_na': 0.5},
    {'group': 'b', 'mean': 3.0, 'percentage_na': 0.3333333333333333}
])
```

In Pandas I was able to do this with this (quite ugly and not optimized) code:

```
df = polars_df.to_pandas()

pd.concat([
    df.groupby(["group"]).apply(lambda g: g.filter(like="val").mean().mean()).rename("mean"),
    df.groupby(["group"]).apply(lambda g: g.filter(like="val").isna().sum().sum() / (g.filter(like="val").shape[0] * g.filter(like="val").shape[1])).rename("percentage_na")
], axis=1)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I rolled back my answer to when the answer is 2.33

```
all_cols_except_val=[x for x in df.columns if "val" not in x]
df.melt(id_vars=all_cols_except_val) \
    .groupby('group') \
    .agg(
        mean=pl.col('value').mean(),
        percent_na=pl.col('value').is_null().sum()/pl.col('value').count()
    )


shape: (2, 3)
┌───────┬──────────┬────────────┐
│ group ┆ mean     ┆ percent_na │
│ ---   ┆ ---      ┆ ---        │
│ str   ┆ f64      ┆ f64        │
╞═══════╪══════════╪════════════╡
│ b     ┆ 3.0      ┆ 0.333333   │
│ a     ┆ 2.333333 ┆ 0.5        │
└───────┴──────────┴────────────┘
```

Comment: I like the use of melt in the beginning, it makes a nice clean solution

Answer (score 2):

With the inspiration of Dean MacGregor and taking your correction that I accidentally calculated the mean of the mean in my pandas code and it actually should be simply the mean over the group I finally came up with this solution:

```
all_cols_except_val=[x for x in df.columns if "val" not in x]

df.melt(id_vars=all_cols_except_val).groupby("group").agg([
    pl.col('value').mean().alias("mean"),
    (pl.col('value').is_null().sum()/pl.col('value').count()).alias("percent_na"),
])
```

Thanks everyone :)

Comment: I rolled back my answer to before it was a mean of means.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a `melt` and `concat`:

```py
In [43]: pl.concat(
    ...:     [
    ...:         polars_df.groupby("group")
    ...:         .agg(pl.exclude("name").mean())
    ...:         .melt("group")
    ...:         .groupby("group")
    ...:         .agg(pl.col("value").mean())
    ...:         .rename({"value": "mean"}),
    ...:         polars_df.groupby("group")
    ...:         .agg(pl.exclude("name").is_null().mean())
    ...:         .melt("group")
    ...:         .groupby("group")
    ...:         .agg(pl.col("value").mean())
    ...:         .drop("group")
    ...:         .rename({"value": "percentage_na"}),
    ...:     ],
    ...:     how="horizontal",
    ...: )
Out[43]:
shape: (2, 3)
┌───────┬──────┬───────────────┐
│ group ┆ mean ┆ percentage_na │
│ ---   ┆ ---  ┆ ---           │
│ str   ┆ f64  ┆ f64           │
╞═══════╪══════╪═══════════════╡
│ a     ┆ 2.0  ┆ 0.5           │
│ b     ┆ 3.0  ┆ 0.333333      │
└───────┴──────┴───────────────┘
```

Not the simplest, seeing if there's a simpler way

Answer (score 1):

Here is my proposal, strongly inspired by @jqurious's first answer.

```
combined_lists = pl.concat_list(r"^val.+$").list().over("group")

df.select(
    'group',
    mean = 
        combined_lists.arr.eval(pl.element().arr.explode()).arr.mean(),
    percentage_na = 
        combined_lists.arr.eval(pl.element().arr.explode().null_count() 
        / pl.element().arr.explode().count()).flatten()
).unique(subset = 'group')

shape: (2, 3)
┌───────┬──────────┬───────────────┐
│ group ┆ mean     ┆ percentage_na │
│ ---   ┆ ---      ┆ ---           │
│ str   ┆ f64      ┆ f64           │
╞═══════╪══════════╪═══════════════╡
│ a     ┆ 2.333333 ┆ 0.5           │
│ b     ┆ 3.0      ┆ 0.333333      │
└───────┴──────────┴───────────────┘
```

As @Dean MacGregor mentioned, I also understand that the average of group a should be 2.33 instead of 2